# Is there anything special in how LINQ query handles references to objects?

Tags: c#, linq, reference

I'm pretty new to C# (coming from a C++ background) and VERY new to LINQ. I'd read that LINQ queries are executed anew each time they are iterated over and will always product the same output unless the underlying data changes.  So I decided to test this out with the code below. Changing an individual element in the array(#2) works as expected, but changing the underlying object (#4) does not:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] scores = new int[] { 97, 92, 81, 60 };

        /* *** NEW CODE *** 

        Func<int[]> funcScores = () => scores;
        Console.WriteLine(funcScores()[0]); // 97 as expected
        scores[0] = 200;
        Console.WriteLine(funcScores()[0]); // 200 as expected
        scores = new int[] { 1000, 2000, 3000 };
        Console.WriteLine(funcScores()[0]); // 1000 as expected

        */

        IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery = GetScores(scores);
        //IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery = GetScores(ref scores); #8

        foreach (int i in scoreQuery)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " "); // #1 outputs 97, 92, 81 as expected
        }

        scores[2] = 343; // #2 change underlying data

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        foreach (int i in scoreQuery)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " "); // #3 outputs 97, 92, 343 as expected
        }

        scores = new int[] { 100, 200, 3, 5, 6 }; // #4 replace underlying object
        //scoreQuery = GetScores(scores); #7

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        foreach (int i in scoreQuery)
        {
            Console.Write(i + " "); // #5 outputs as #3 rather than 100, 200
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        foreach (var item in scores)
        {
            Console.Write(item + "\t"); // #6 sanity check scores is 100,200,3,5,6
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> GetScores(int[] scores)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("non-ref version");
        return from score in scores
               where score > 80
               select score;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> GetScores(ref int[] scores)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ref version");
        return from score in scores
               where score > 80
               select score;
    }
```

Recreating the query (#7) would 'fix' it, but not quite what I intended.  So I thought all I'd need to do would be to pass scores by ref (#8), but that makes no difference.

Where am I going wrong? I think I have a disconnect in my understanding of references versus variables containing them, or is this something specific to how LINQ queries are made?

Comment: In your `ref` version you're still passing the original reference to the LINQ methods by value - you're not changing the value of `scores` *in the method* so it makes no difference that it's passed by reference.

Comment: `from score in scores` - here scores is the _captured_ parameter, not a global.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but after reading @henk-holterman 's comment I went off and found an old article about variable capturing.  I then wrote the code I've just added to the top of the original code above.  I am probably comparing apples to oranges, but this behaves how I expected (read: hoped) the LINQ code would work.  Thanks for the answers so far, I will read them all.

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery = GetScores(scores);
```

scoreQuery actually holds a reference to score.  Then on line:

```
scores = new int[] { 100, 200, 3, 5, 6 };
```

you create a new array, and replace the reference stored in variable scores, but scoreQuery still references the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is not with LINQ, but with general OOP:
No matter how you pass the initial array to `GetScores` that object is always referenced by the `IEnumerable<int>` returned by the method. Changing the reference in your calling method later does not change that other reference.

Answer (score 0):

This quote:

> I'd read that LINQ queries are executed anew each time they are iterated over and will always product the same output unless the underlying data changes.

Refers to the fact that if the data in the source object changes, and you reiterate the query, the new iteration will reflect the changes in the source object. It does not refer to changing the source object with another object.

All LINQ operators take their parameter by value. For example `Select`:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
```

These LINQ methods are what query syntax uses, so passing the parameter as `ref` to your method makes no difference as they will be passed by value to the underlying LINQ method.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this line:

```
scores = new int[] { 100, 200, 3, 5, 6 }; // #4 replace underlying object
```

you just re-reference `scores` to another array which has *nothing* to do with the one passed to the `GetScores`-method initially. This has nothing to do with LINQ, it's about how reference-types (and that's what an array is) are dealt when passed to methods.

Consider this:

```
var myValue = new MyObject { MyProperty = 1 };
DoSomething(myValue);
```

Now when you re-assign `myValue` like this:

```
myVale = new MyObject { MyProperty = 5 };
```

how do you expect `DoSomething` to reflect this? It doesn´t know *anything* about the new instance, as it was called with the original one. The same happens in your code: `GetScores` will just create an iterator based on the instance passed to it. Creating a new instance won´t change how that iterator works.